# Azure AD B2C : Back option to previous orchestration step in user journey

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a requirement to give option to user to edit the details he has given in previous steps.

Example:
OrchestrationStep 1: Collect user info like name, email, country
OrchestrationStep 2: Send email verification and verify the email. Here there should be an option change his details like email. When user click on that link, we should show step 1. Else continue to Step 3.
OrchestrationStep 3: Collect other details like password.

How to implement this?

Comment: What if orchestration step 2 shows the email collected in step 1, and verifies that. If the email is incorrect, the user can fix it in step 2 and will be forced to verify again. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

In the B2C, the user sign-up flow follows this steps for the local account with email:

1. Verify the email by sending the code
2. Set password
3. Collect user info like name, email, country

[image]

Note: If you enable MFA, when you click **create**, it will redirect to the MFA page to verify the user.

Comment: I understand that. these three steps you mentioned will happen through 1 orchestration step in user journey. But what i mentioned is orchestration steps. My question was how to go back to orchestration step 1 from orchestration step 2 if user wants to change anything in what user filled already.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way for you want. And the whole sign-up process is in one page.